# variable number of capturing groups

Tags: regex, xpath

I have a xpath expression which I want to use to extract City and date from a td which contains a string of this kind:

```
City(may contain spaces and may be missing, but the following space is always present) on 2013/07/20
```

So far, I got to the following solution for extracting the date, which works partially:

```
//path/to/my/td/text()/replace(.,'(.*) on (.*)','$3')
```

This works when City is present, but when City is missing I get "on 2013/07/20" as a result.
I think this is because the first capturing group fails and so the number of groups is different.
How can I get this expression to work?

Comment: Puzzling indeed. When I run the expression on http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi I get the same result with input such as `<p class="test"> on 11/12/2013</p>`. (By the way, you meant `$2` not `$3` right? with $3 I can't capture with input with City present.) I may have found the problem in that it seems the string convertion is whitespace-normalized: when you run `concat('[', //p[@class="test"], ']')` you get `[on 11/12/2013]` not `[ on 11/12/2013]`. I can't read anything about whitespace normalization on by default on string() in http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully check your regex, but it looks fine at first sight. Anyway, you can also go an easier way if you only want to get the date by extracting the text after "on ":

```
//path/to/my/td/text()/substring-after(.,'on ')
```

*edit:* or you may go the substring-way and select the last 10 characters of the content:

```
//path/to/my/td/text()/substring(., string-length(.) - 9)
```

Comment: This will fail for a horrible large set of cities. For example, run this against the factbook XML document: `//city/name[contains(., 'on ')]`, it returns cities containing the word "on" like "Stratford on Avon", but also some like "Milton Keynes". In factbook there are 24 results, but it only contains the larger cities; expect much more to fail.

Comment: I added an additional way to my original answer, which should work in all cases where an ISO date is at the end of the string.

Comment: As a grumpy old man, I must protest that Stratford on Avon and Milton Keynes are not cities, they are towns.